# What Output type this method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return anonymous type from LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358200/return-anonymous-type-from-linq-query)

I use this Method:

```
public static ... GetList()
    {
        Entity conn = new Entity();
        var lst = (from PS in conn.PurchaserSpecials
                select new
                {
                    PS.PurchaserID,
                    PS.PurchaserSerial,
                    PS.Purchaser.Address,
                    PS.Purchaser.Fax,
                    PS.Purchaser.NumberEconomic
                }).ToList();
return lst;
    }
```

can not use var for output Type. Please help me...

what is output the method?

Comment: Well, it's two things :) It's an object type, because that's what the methode returns, but the linq query returns an annonymous type-list (select new {..} creates an annonymous type)

Comment: `lst` variable is of anonymous type, that means you can use it only within your method. You have to use a well known class to solve your issue.

Comment: The debugger holds the answer you seek

Answer (score 2):

It's a list of the anonymous type you created.

If you want to return a type that you would know, create a new class that has the fields you are selecting (I am guessing types below):

```
public class Specials
    {
        public int PurchaserID { get; set; }
        public int PurchaserSerial { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int Fax { get; set; }
        public int NumberEconomic { get; set; }
    }

public static List<Specials> GetList()
    {
        Entity conn = new Entity();
        var lst = (from PS in conn.PurchaserSpecials
                select new Specials
                {
                    PurchaserID =  PS.PurchaserID,
                    PurchaserSerial = PS.PurchaserSerial,
                    Address = PS.Purchaser.Address,
                    Fax = PS.Purchaser.Fax,
                    NumberEconomic = PS.Purchaser.NumberEconomic
                }).ToList();
return lst;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You LINQ query generates an anonymous type, and as such can't be used as a return type of the method, and the calling method will not know anything about the return type.

A way around this is to make use of the dynamic keyword and dynamic types.

The return type of you method can be like this

```
public dynamic GetList() {
        return ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of the query is an anonymous type which you can not return back as a parameter. To be simple, better you create a class something like : **'PurchaseDetail'** with all those properties and return the code like :

```
public static List<PurchaseDetail> GetList() 
    { 
        Entity conn = new Entity(); 
        var lst = (from PS in conn.PurchaserSpecials 
                select new PurchaseDetail
                { 
                    PurchaserID= PS.PurchaserID, 
                    PurchaserSerial=PS.PurchaserSerial, 
                    Address=PS.Purchaser.Address, 
                    Fax=PS.Purchaser.Fax, 
                    NumberEconomic =PS.Purchaser.NumberEconomic 
                }).ToList(); 
return lst; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Return Type would be the `List of type Products`

```
public static List<Products> GetList()
{
    Entity conn = new Entity();
    var lst = (from PS in conn.PurchaserSpecials
            select new
            {
                PS.PurchaserID,
                PS.PurchaserSerial,
                PS.Purchaser.Address,
                PS.Purchaser.Fax,
                PS.Purchaser.NumberEconomic
            }).ToList();
    return lst;
}

public class Products
{
    //Properties you are using in the query.
}
```